# How to add images into Adobe Flex RichTextEditor?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, rich-text-editor

How to add images into [Adobe Flex RichTextEditor control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_10.html)? I mean **using a button** =)

So we have some text editor with RTE a-la 
[editor screenshot http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/RTE1.png](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/RTE1.png)

We want to get into its content images using some button. How to do such thing?

BTW: I found this http://anotherflava.com/2009/01/12/flex-xhtml-rich-text-editor-w-images/ but I really do not understand how to make it work so if any one can publish simple project with simple (DIRTY IS OK) source it would be grate!)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RichTextEditor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/RichTextEditor.html) is a complex component which consist of few small components and [TextArea](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextArea.html). So the problem is how to insert image in TextArea.

TextArea can render simple HTML and `<img>` tag is supported. More about htmlText property [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html).

So

```
var myTextEditor:RichTextEditor = new RichTextEditor();
myTextEditor.htmlText = "<img src='myImage.jpg' />"
```