# Insert Image from RichText Editor Adobe flex directly from editor

Tags: html, image, apache-flex, adobe, rich-text-editor

I am trying to find a way to add, directly from a RTE in Adobe Flex, an image.
I tried several ways some suggested in other websites, such as:

```
<img src="xxx/>
[img src="xxx/]
<img src="xxx></>
<img source="xxx/>
[IMG]xxx[/IMG]
```

I just need to be able, using an HTML code or something, to add an image in the editor.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer help? [How to add images into adobe flex richtexteditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164725/how-to-add-images-into-adobe-flex-richtexteditor)

Comment: Nope. But I found a workaround, did not fix the issue though.